# Upload image to Firebase storage for each object in Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am creating a news feed type app, where each post has an id, some text, and an image. I am developing this app for Android

So tree in my Firebase Database has three elements: postID, postText and postImage.

Now, I am wondering if I can upload images for each post to Firebase Storage and then take the link for each one and put it in the tree for my postImage?

Everytime I take the link directly and copy and paste it in, it doesn't show as a link to the image.

I have seen links appearing underlined in other peoples JSON trees, so I was wondering if it can be done this way? Or do you need to push the images from the app directly.

Comment: You seem to have tried something that didn't give the result that you expected. Please provide clear steps to reproduce what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what you saw happen instead.

Comment: What I tried: Uploaded image from local computer to firebase storage. Copied the direct link to image in firebase storage and pasted it in Firebase Database for postImage element in JSON tree. What I expected to happen: That the direct link to the image would render as a link (underlined). What I saw happen: The image just pasted in as text, and when I tried to pull that post down into a list view my app, it just rendered as text (the link to the image was just text)

Comment: It's hard to imagine what's going on here because there's no code or visuals that specifically describe things.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at Zero To App (video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE, source: https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c#file-chatmessageviewholder-java-L32-L37) where we do this same thing (store a string containing the download URL, download it appropriately)